# How to group all sibling nodes from different parents by common sibling in a graph using Gremlin

Tags: graph, graph-databases, gremlin

It is difficult for me to describe. The Gremlin query I am trying to write has one node as an input. Then I am searching all the nodes with class Group of input. Then in each group there is only one Text class node and a number of Elem nodes.
I would like to get all the Elem nodes that have as a sibling the same Text node even if they are from different Group nodes. You see the different color of groupings.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

What I have so far:

```
g = new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/graphdb")
v = g.v('#12:109')
v.bothE.has('@class','hasElem').outV.has('@class','Group').bothE.or(_().has('@class','hasText'), _().has('@class','hasElem').except([v])).inV().except([v])
```

This returns to me all the green and blue nodes together, but I don't know how to do the grouping.

Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It took 5hours but I found the query that does it:

The `groupBy` mapping basically takes as a key the Text node `{it}` and as a value the leaf from text->parent->sibling `{it.inE.outV.outE.inV.hasNot('@class','Text').except([v])}` that is not of class Text except for the Input. The last line `m.sort{a,b -> b.value.size() <=> a.value.size()}` is sorting Texts in descending popularity, or in other words the ones that have the longer list of related siblings are coming first.

```
g = new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/graphdb")
v = g.v('#12:109')
m = [:]  
v.bothE.has('@class','hasElem').outV.has('@class','hasElem').dedup().bothE.has('@class','hasText').inV().groupBy(m){it}{it.inE.outV.outE.inV.hasNot('@class','Text').except([v])}
m.sort{a,b -> b.value.size() <=> a.value.size()}
```